# Best approach to determine which data values are set

Tags: c#

I decode a response from a device and get different values back. Those values can vary: 1,2 or 3 data types (double, int or string) and mixed. E.g. For command X I get 1 string back, for command Y I get 1 string and 2 double back,...

The (simplified) class I use right now for the response:

```
 public class DecodedResponse
{
    public CommandEnum command;
    public double ReturnValueD1;
    public double ReturnValueD2;
    public double ReturnValueD3;

    public string ReturnValueS1;
    public string ReturnValueS2;
    public string ReturnValueS3;

    public int ReturnValueI1;
    public int ReturnValueI2;
    public int ReturnValueI3;
}
```

Until now, the user had to know which values ​​are set for the command X,Y,... 
But I'm not very happy with that. What could be a clever solution to tell the user which values are set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you get each response for specific request - you know what response you should expect.

I would create separate classes for each command response with only these fields/properties which are valid for this command. Using one, simplified class as you mentioned causes problems as you described and require many `if` statements to proper command handling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could be a solution.